# Workaround static block inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, static-initialization

I know my question can seem bizarre so I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

Let's say I have a class A and multiples classes B1...n extending A

I want to, whenever I write a subclass B1...N of A, enforce writing of a static block in that subclass.

In my case, I want to add some string representing the subclass to some global list available at the start of my program, right after compilation.

I thought about using reflection but my program would need to scan every classes and if I do it this way I can't enforce every subclass to implement this static initializer.

Hope I'm clear enough, if you have any thoughts... Thank you

Comment: I think I know what your talking about. Check out PrimaryKey: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/util/PrimaryKey.java The idea is/was to standardize equals and hashcode implemention across DAOs by using the underlying data (ie String, numbers, etc) they represent. (I apologize to all who think I have abused the term Primary Key here) I couldn't figure out a good way to achieve such via inheritance, so what I did was create a bunch of static methods in my PrimaryKey class that could be called as one-liners in DAO classes. Let me know if this example helped?